# How to stop / kill Windows Service in debug mode in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, service, windows-services, visual-studio-debugging

I installed a Windows Service on Local machine and Started it from the Services Control Manager. Then I opened its C#.Net Solution in Visual Studio 2013, went to "Attach to process" screen and attached to the service successfully. VS2013 switched to debug mode and then the process hit its first breakpoint. I did some debugging and then wanted to kill the Service right at a point (basically didn't want it to run rest of the code). So, while holding execution at a breakpoint I went to Services Control Manager and tried to send a Stop command. After few minutes I got a message that no command can be successfully sent to the Service. Then, I clicked on "Stop debugging" button in VS2013. That brought me out of debug mode in VS2013 but it seems that the Service still went ahead and executed rest of the code in background. I could see updates in Database which I wanted to hold back.

Question is, in such scenario how can I stop / kill the Service at a certain Breakpoint so that it won't execute rest of the code?

Comment: In the Windows Task Manager, in the Services tab find the service you want to kill. Right click the service and click on Go to process. The selected process (if any) is the one corresponding to your service. Kill this process.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do this in VS, but when I debug services in C++Builder, attaching to a service process and then stopping the debugger kills the process being debugged.  It sounds like VS is simply detaching from the process instead.  See if there is an option to have VS not do that anymore.  Or use Task Manager to kill the process, like @ForguesR suggested (assuming you have rights to kill system processes - having a debugger kill the process can get around that, at least on older OS versions before UAC).